# Python defined peek iterator, get the error "'list' object is not callable"

Tags: python

I try to defined a peek iterator class manually, the peek function just return the iterator pointer value, but not move on. 
The generator class has next() and has_next() function, and the PeekIterator class I add the peek() function, but when call the peek function, it get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iterater.py", line 63, in <module>
    test.peek()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Could you please help to check what's the issue here ? Thank you !

```
class generator:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.has_next():
            i = self.i
            self.i += 1
            return i
        else:
            print "there is NO next value."
            return None
            #raise StopIteration()

    def has_next(self):
        if self.i >= self.n:
            return False
        else:
            return True
class PeekIterator:
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.peek = []
        self.generator = generator

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def peek(self):
        if self.peek == []:
            if self.has_next():
                cur = self.generator.next()
                self.peek.append(cur)
                print "cur: ", cur
                return cur
        else:
            return self.peek[-1]

    def has_next(self):
        if not self.generator.has_next() and not self.peek:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def get_next(self):
        if not self.peek:
            if self.has_next():
                return self.generator.next()
        else:
            ret = self.peek[-1]
            self.peek.pop()
            return ret

gen = generator(5)
test = PeekIterator(gen)
print test.has_next()
print test.get_next()
print test.get_next()
test.peek()
```

~

Comment: If you rename the list you are still going to get an error as you cannot call an int, use self._peek as the name and just use `test.peek `

Answer (score 2):

```
class PeekIterator:
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.peek = []
#...
    def peek(self):
```

You have two `peek`s here - one method, and one list. One will overwrite the other. When you do `test.peek()`, Python thinks you're referring to list and not the method.

Consider renaming one of these to something else. Ex. Change the list to `self.items`.

Comment: I would recommend rename `self.peek` to `self.__peek`. It's good practice to hide fields using private prefix "__".